# Type checking for MagicMock spies

Tags: python, python-typing, typechecking

When wrapping a class in a MagicMock I want to keep type checking and intellisense for both MagicMock and the wrapped class methods.

Currently I achieve this by using the below code. Is there a better  (less verbose) way?

```
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class MockedSomeClass(MagicMock, SomeClass):
        pass
else:
    MockedSomeClass = TypeVar('MockedSomeClass')

...

spy: MockedSomeClass = MagicMock(wraps=SomeClass)
```

Comment: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213

Comment: @daniilfajnberg so no other solution for now. Thanks.